# Accessing notepad++ from cygwin bash

Tags: command-line, bash, notepad++, cygwin, c

So when I am writing code, I use notepad++ and when I am done, I copy-paste it to plain old notepad because I use Cygwin and notepad is the only text editor that I know how to access from the shell. Could someone teach me how to go from the prompt directly to N++?

Comment: Are text files automatically opened with Notepad or Notepad++ ?

Answer (score 0):

To launch `notepad++.exe` with the shell path to the file converted to
a proper windows path, you may use the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe `cygpath.exe -w "$*"`
```

The path to `notepad++.exe` may vary.

[source](https://coderwall.com/p/jxyjdq/opening-files-in-notepad-from-cygwin)